# Magento Front End Developer Certification

Tags: magento-1.7, certification

I need to prepare for the [Magento Front End Developer Certification](http://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/front-end-developer) and there didn't seem to be a question on this yet. How should one prepare for this certification? Are there some guides and/or test exams that I can go through? Please note that I am looking specifically for  Front End Certification material. There just doesn't seem to be any information regarding this exam or a study guide.

Comment: Here is the link to the course description mentioned in your post - Core Principles of Theming in Magento - http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/descriptions#core-principles-for-theming-in-magento

Comment: i'm preparing myself too. Feel free to contact me so we can help ourselves. thanks

Comment: The correct link to Robert Kent's git book is now [this](http://robkent.gitbooks.io/magento-front-end-developer-test-questions/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a study guide available in PDF form from Magento's website. The test is multiple choice, and takes about 90 minutes to complete.

You can get the study guide here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/front-end-developer - click on 'Resources'

Most of the test revolves around XML layouts and theme fallback. Some questions focus on basic CSS principles. Here's the actual breakdown of the distribution of questions:

```
Design fallback - 7%
XML Layout - 19%
Customization of template files - 16%
Block template system - 11%
Locate files / directory structure - 7%
Javascript creation & Customization - 8%
CSS principles - 9%
Customizing look and feel - 12%
Admin Configuration scope - 6%
Internationalization - 4%
```

The test as described by Magento:

> A Magento frontend engineer:
>
> Creates and customizes Magento themes including: templates, layouts,
>   CSS, Javascript, and other components of the front end of a Magento
>   site images translations
>
> Uses the Admin Panel to: implement design-related system configuration
>   modify the appearance of specific pages (for instance, CMS,
>   categories, and products)
>
> About the Exam
>
> 65 multiple-choice questions
>
> 90 minutes to complete the exam
>
> Each question on the exam tests a skill that applies to both Community
>   Edition v.1.7 and Enterprise Edition v.1.12.
>
> No hard-copy or online materials may be referenced during the exam
>
> No prerequisites; we recommend taking [Core Principles of Theming in
>   Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/descriptions#core-principles-for-theming-in-magento) course as a first step
>
> Study Guide Available

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/front-end-developer

Comment: FWIW, I have used Magento professionally since 2008 and I am a Certified Developer. I took the FEDC exam without studying on the day it was released and passed.

Comment: I am also a certified developer - I already went through that link and they just sent me a normal study guide. How different are the questions?

Comment: Very different. See my answer. The study guide is at the link I just sent you. I tried it now - it did send the correct one.

Comment: Uploading the guide now to this link. You should be able to download it from there. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11391/FEDC_Study_Guide_v.1.0.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Despite the official study guide mentioned by @philwinkle, I would like to add two more resources which can be quite helpful in order to prepare for the Magento Frontend Developer Certification:

1. Demac Media compiled answers to the questions of the official study guide [here](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-frontend-developer-certification-exam-study-guide-qa/).
2. Robert Kent started a git book full with structured test questions [here](http://robkent.gitbooks.io/magento-front-end-developer-test-questions/). I personally had the feeling that his questions are a bit easier than the official ones in the exam, so be warned.